# Finding Scheduler Delay for Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I want to be able to generate a table for the metric for each task, like the one on the Collector Spark UI when you visit a particular stage.

One of the columns is Scheduler delay, which I cannot find in any of the REST api provided by Spark.

All the other columns exists (when I browse /api/v1/applications/[app-id]/stages/[stage-id]/[attempt]/taskList).

How is scheduler delay calculate/is there a way for me to pull that data out without scraping the Collector Spark UI webpage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheduler delay is not provided in the history api, yes. For the UI, it is calculated as follows:

```
private[ui] def getSchedulerDelay(info: TaskInfo, metrics: TaskMetricsUIData, currentTime: Long): Long = {
    if (info.finished) {
        val totalExecutionTime = info.finishTime - info.launchTime
        val executorOverhead = (metrics.executorDeserializeTime + metrics.resultSerializationTime)
        math.max(0,totalExecutionTime - metrics.executorRunTime - executorOverhead - getGettingResultTime(info, currentTime))
    } else {
        // The task is still running and the metrics like executorRunTime are not available.
        0L
    }
}
```

see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ui/jobs/StagePage.scala line number 770

Answer (score 0):

At least for spark 1.6, if you are looking for scheduling delay for spark streaming batch, you can look at [spark streaming UI source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/ui/StreamingPage.scala).

It uses a Class [BatchUIData](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/ui/BatchUIData.scala#L43), in which `scheduling delay` is defined:

```
/**
 * Time taken for the first job of this batch to start processing from the time this batch
 * was submitted to the streaming scheduler. Essentially, it is
 * `processingStartTime` - `submissionTime`.
 */
def schedulingDelay: Option[Long] = processingStartTime.map(_ - submissionTime)
```